# Generate random values from array using Java

Tags: java, arrays, random

I'm running a java program to generate random values from arrays. When I run the program I am getting a java.util.Random@39ed3c8d value. I know I have to override a certain class but not entirely sure how to go about it. Please can anyone assist

```
import java.util.Random;
class RandomArray{
public static void main(String[]args){
String suite[] = { "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"};
Object[] suiteNumber = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"jack","king","queen"};
Random suiteType = new Random(); 
int n = suiteType.nextInt(4);
Random numberOnSuite = new Random();
int m = numberOnSuite.nextInt(11); 
System.out.println(numberOnSuite.toString()+" "+suite[n]);
}
}
```

This is the output below
[image]

Comment: I guess you want `int m = numberOnSuite.nextInt(suiteNumber.length);` and `System.out.println(suiteNumber[m]+" "+suite[n]);`. Your code tries to print the `Random` object which basically is a random number generator (and thus the names `suiteType` and `numberOnSuite` are _very_ misleading).

Comment: What exacly do you want to achieve? What do you expect to be written in the console?

Comment: I see I made a very silly error. I meant to have the index of suiteNumber and instead I was now using numberOnSuite

Comment: You don't need more than one ```Random``` It's 'suit' btw, not 'suite'